# Jquery Code not working when placed in head tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some jquery code which doesn't work when placed inside the head tag but works when placed after the body tag. Even though it is inside document.ready()  it isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (i = 1950; i <= new Date().getFullYear(); i++) {
        $('#from').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
        $('#to').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
    }
})
```

Here is my Structure

```
 < head>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/easyoffice/js/excelExport.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/easyoffice/js/tinytable.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (i = 1950; i <= new Date().getFullYear(); i++) {
        $('#from').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
        $('#to').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));

    }

})
      function checkyear() {
    var from = $('select[id=to]').val();
    var to = $('select[id=from]').val();
    if (from == 'Select' || to == 'Select') {
        alert(" Please Select an Year  ")
        return false;
    } else if (from <= to) {

        alert(" Please Select an Year greater than From Year ")
        $("select#to").prop('selectedIndex', 0);

        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

   </script>
   </head>
```

Comment: What error do you see in console?

Comment: where are you importing the jquery lib? Before or after <body> tag?

Comment: what is the structure of the html page? where is the jquery script tag located? it needs to be included before your script

Comment: @MageshKumaar   in the head

Comment: @kuttanpillai before or after the script block in your question?

Comment: can you please share the code that shows the structure. Also provide the errors if any in the browser console

Comment: @MoLow  i imports all scripts and stylesheets in the head and then  writes the functions...

Comment: please include a fiddle

Comment: FYI, a quick optimisation of your `for` loop - `for (var i = 1950, d = new Date().getFullYear(); i <= d; i++)`

Comment: i thing you are operating with attribute of html which is not present in head because its present in body tag

Comment: Please see my edited question

Comment: @Phil  thank you, please see my edited question

Comment: In your updated code `< head>` tag have space it should be `<head>`. I am wondering before completion of `head` tag you have completed `script` tag two time.. it may have issue

Comment: @HareshVidja .. itz a typo  here

Comment: Always copy / paste **actual code**. Don't type it in here

Comment: Okk.. Sorry for that

Comment: please check console.log there is any error message in syntax of javascript code? or any error in other two javascript file which you have added.

Comment: Your have 2 script close tag `</script>
   </script>`

Comment: @HareshVidja  . Nop i dont have any error regarding js files, and also there are two errors in console  regarding two css files which in this case not an issue

Comment: Missing semicolons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem. I put the ready function after the `<body>` tag and now it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

please check sequence of where you have added yout jquery file in head tag?
it should be

```
<script src="your_jquery_library_file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
//Then
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
          for (i = 1950; i <= new Date().getFullYear(); i++) {
        $('#from').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
        $('#to').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));

        }
      })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready() simply ensures that all DOM elements are loaded before your javascript is loaded.

**When it doesn't matter**

Without waiting for this event to fire, you may end up manipulating DOM elements or styles that are yet to exist on the page. the DOM ready event also allows you more flexibility to run scripts on different parts of the page. For example:

```
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById('map').style.opacity = 0;
    </script>
```

will run because the map div has been loaded before the script runs. In fact, you can get some pretty good performance improvements by placing your scripts at the bottom of the page.

**When it does matter**

However, if you are loading your scripts in the  element, most of your DOM has not loaded. This example will not work:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('map').style.opacity = 0;
    </script>
    <div id="map"></div>
```

will not, since the map div has not been loaded.

It'll all depend on when certain parts of the code are executed.
If they're in the header, then the elements they are attempting to access might/will* not exist yet.

Comment: great explanation  . i've heard  placing the scripts after or inside body tag is not a good practise, thats why i asked this question..